# Why is this basic GPA Calculator returning a KeyError?

Tags: python, list

```
Grade1 = input ('Grade for Class 1?')
Grade2 = input ('Grade for Class 2?')
Grade3 = input ('Grade for Class 3?')
Grade4 = input ('Grade for Class 4?')

Grades = (str(Grade1), str(Grade2), str(Grade3), str(Grade4))

def average(numbers):
    total= sum(numbers)
    return total/len(numbers)

def RealGPA(semestergrades):
    PointValues = {'A+': 4.2, 'A':4.0, 'A-': 3.7, 'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 'B-': 2.7, 'C+': 2.3, 'C':2.0, 'C-': 1.7, 'D+': 1.3, 'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7, 'F': 0.00}
    PointsEarned= []
    for Grade in Grades:
        Values=(PointValues[Grades])
        PointsEarned.append(Values)
return average(PointsEarned)

print (RealGPA(Grades))
```

It says "Key error: ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A') if you type in A for all the inputs-- which is weird, because 'A' is present in PointValues. Am I doing inputs incorrectly?

Comment: PointValues[Grades] should be PointValues[Grade]

Comment: You aren't using the argument `semestergrades` in your `RealGPA` function. Your global `Grades` tuple is used instead of your local variable.

Answer (score 0):

`PointValues[Grades]` looks for the tuple `(str(Grade1), str(Grade2), str(Grade3), str(Grade4))` in the `PointValues` dictionary, which obviously generates a `KeyError`.

Perhaps you meant `PointValues[Grade]`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple typo - you have written `Grades` instead of `Grade`.

Added a few other changes as well (have a look at the PEP8 style guide):

```
grade1 = input ('Grade for Class 1?')
grade2 = input ('Grade for Class 2?')
grade3 = input ('Grade for Class 3?')
grade4 = input ('Grade for Class 4?')

grades = (str(grade1), str(grade2), str(grade3), str(grade4))

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    return total/len(numbers)

def real_GPA(semestergrades):
    point_values = {'A+': 4.2, 'A':4.0, 'A-': 3.7, 'B+': 3.3, 'B': 3.0, 
                    'B-': 2.7, 'C+': 2.3, 'C':2.0, 'C-': 1.7, 'D+': 1.3, 
                    'D': 1.0, 'D-': 0.7, 'F': 0.00}
    points_earned = []
    for grade in grades:
        values = point_values[grade]
        points_earned.append(values)
return average(points_earned)

print(real_GPA(grades))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo. This `Values=(PointValues[Grades])` would be `Values=(PointValues[Grade])`. And also function name and variable name should be all lower case.